# unknown sqlite error - java mac os 10.5 - unsatisfied link error

Tags: java, sqlite

I just recently started getting this error for a completely unknown reason.

The code has not changed since last run time.

Any ideas?

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/l8/l8xdyr88GEO5adGKtmu9XU+++TI/-Tmp-/sqlite-3.7.2-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /private/var/folders/l8/l8xdyr88GEO5adGKtmu9XU+++TI/-Tmp-/sqlite-3.7.2-libsqlitejdbc.jnilib: unknown required load command 0x80000022`

update on root cause:

`java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(mySQL);`

where mySQL = "jdbc:sqlite:/Users/Jason/seeking.db"

This file 100% exists. This connection attempt is causing the error.

//////////////SOLUTION:

I had switched my java (Mac system preferences for java) preference to load Java SE 6 as a priority. This will not work with the SQLite jdbc library.

J2SE 5.0 is needed for this library to behave properly (it seems).

Hope this helps someone else down the road!!

Comment: any pointers are really appreciated...hitting my head against a wall on this and i am really unsure how to better ask this question.. thank you

Comment: The file exists, ok, but does the process have the proper access rights to it?

Comment: it was working previously. the only difference is that i recently tried to install Kannel (unrelated). it is quite opaque to me, but if there is anything i can check i would be interested to know how to debug this.

Comment: i also just tested the database using an external vendor application. connects perfectly and queries with no issue.

Comment: I cannot help you further. Sorry.

Comment: You can answer your own question as an answer below and accept it. :)

Comment: But don't write "solved" in the title. Do it the proper way: add an answer, accept it.

Comment: was not able in the time i posted it. the question is too new.